# CPU Instruction Traces for Memory Access

Tags: cpu, cpu-architecture

Can anyone help me where can i get/find the CPU instruction traces for memory accesses (both read and write). I want to use this traces as an input to a DDR3 SDRAM Simulator.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a Pin tool [Intel dynamic binary instrumentation framework](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/pintool/docs/97554/Pin/html/index.html) for that. In fact there is an example tool that you can directly use, called pinatrace - PIN tool for tracing memory accesses. Only catch is it works only on x86 systems.

You can explore the link mentioned above to learn how to design such tools of your own. Link also provide a lot of examples. But if you only want to use it then the command will be:

```
pin -t pinatrace.so -- (application you want to collect trace of)
```

Use appropriate path of pin and pinatrace.so (it is there in ManualExample folder). Output trace would be in pinatrace.out

Comment: Does `pin` not work on AMD x86 CPUs?  I didn't think it used any HW performance counters or anything else Intel-specific.  Or did you mean it will only work on x86 systems?

Comment: It will work on x86 compatible platforms. So it will work on AMD x86  CPU's as well. No it does not use any HW performance counter registers but JIT framework of PIN expect x86 compatible binaries.